# ConTeXt: Hyphens for sequential page numbers in an index (register)

Tags: context, indexing

## Background

Page numbers in an index are often formatted using hyphens for references on consecutive pages, such as:

```
1, 4-7, 10
```

## Code

Consider the following example:

```
\defineregister[photographer][]

\setupregister[photographer][
  pagestyle=normal,
  indicator=no,
]

\starttext 
  First 
  \photographer{Yousuf Karsh} \page
  Second 
  \photographer{Yousuf Karsh} \page
  Third 
  \photographer{Yousuf Karsh} \page
  Fourth 
  \photographer{Yousuf Karsh} 

  \completephotographer
\stoptext
```

## Problem

I would like to produce the behaviour of hyphenated page numbers using ConTeXt, however the example code produces:

[image: Page numbers]

I thought that it would produce `1-4` instead of `1, 2, 3, 4`. The [documentation](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Registers#Tricks) describes two "tricks" to accomplish this feature:

1. Automatically collapse page ranges: `[[Command/{{{1}}}|\{{{1}}}]]`. I have no idea what that means or how to use it -- there is no complete example. Also, other [documentation](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupregister) indicates not to use command, opting for `pagecommand` or `textcommand` instead.
2. Use `\startregister[index][mymouse]{mouse} ... \stopregister[index][mymouse]`. This does not apply in my case because I don't know when the last consecutive reference will be added to the document: the document is created dynamically.

## Question

How do you collapse page ranges in ConTeXt when you don't know where the first and last references are inserted into the document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option you need is [`compress=yes`](https://gitorious.org/context/context/source/4a0e1a196924d87dd4b148e20236bff7ee9e4ca2:tex/context/base/strc-reg.mkiv#L76) which *compresses* consecutive entries into a range with hyphen.

As a side note, generally a `\definesomething` takes the same arguments as
`\setupsomething`, so you can shorten the example:

```
\defineregister
  [photographer]
  [compress=yes]

\starttext
  \dorecurse{4}{%%
    Foo
    \photographer{Yousuf Karsh} \page}

  \completephotographer
\stoptext
```

[image: result]

Comment: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupregister is now updated. Thank you.